# What can I use instead of joinToString to solve my problem

Tags: java, kotlin

I got a task but I don't know how to solve it.

Create a 3x3x3 three-dimensional list that contains elements of type Int and is filled with zeros (0).

Print the list of lists in one string (just use `print()` or `println()` function).

My code is:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var ans = mutableListOf(
        mutableListOf(0, 0, 0), 
        mutableListOf(0, 0, 0), 
        mutableListOf(0, 0, 0), 
        mutableListOf(0, 0, 0), 
        mutableListOf(0, 0, 0), 
        mutableListOf(0, 0, 0), 
        mutableListOf(0, 0, 0), 
        mutableListOf(0, 0, 0), 
        mutableListOf(0, 0, 0)
    )
    println(ans.joinToString("\n")) 
}
```

But it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Note part of the problem is you didn't create a 3x3x3 three-dimensional list. You have a 9x3 two-dimensional list.

Answer (score 3):

You created 9x3 two dimensional list. Use List function instead:

```
fun main() {
    val ans = List(3) { List(3) { MutableList(3) { 0 } } }
    println(ans)
}
```

or Array:

```
fun main() {
    val ans = Array(3) { Array(3) { IntArray(3) { 0 } } }
    println(ans.contentDeepToString())
}
```

Comment: Note you can do this with a list as well: `val ans = List(3) { List(3) { List(3) { 0 } } } }`.

Comment: The question is about a 3x3x3 three-dimensional _list_, not about an array. And since there is no _contentDeepToString_ for lists this does not really answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

@Slaw gave the correct answer in a comment to @FeelFree's answer:

```
val ans = List(3) { List(3) { List(3) { 0 } } }
```

The mistake with the code in your question is that – as @Slaw commented below your question – you are not building a 3 x 3 x 3 list, but a 9 x 3 one.

To built a 3 x 3 x 3 list 'manually' like in your question you would do:

```
val ans = listOf(
  listOf(
    listOf(0, 0, 0),
    listOf(0, 0, 0),
    listOf(0, 0, 0)
  ),
  listOf(
    listOf(0, 0, 0),
    listOf(0, 0, 0),
    listOf(0, 0, 0)
  ),
  listOf(
    listOf(0, 0, 0),
    listOf(0, 0, 0),
    listOf(0, 0, 0)
  )
)
```

Printout possibilities:

```
// Everything on one line

println(ans)

[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]

// Each outer list on its own line

input.forEach(::println)  

input.forEach { println(it) }

for(list in input) {
  println(list)
}

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

// Each inner list on its own line

input.forEachIndexed { index, outerList ->
  println("[")
  outerList.forEach { innerList -> println("  $innerList") }
  print("]")
  if (index == input.size - 1) println() else println(",")
}

[
  [0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0]
],
[
  [0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0]
],
[
  [0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0]
]
```